# Data-Frame contain values doesn't work with "np.where" and there is a valueerror

Tags: python, dataframe

I wrote the below code in python to adjust my currencies to be based on USD. It works piece by piece perfectly but as a whole , it gives me the below error:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,8) (17072,) (17072,)

Can anyone please help me to find the issue ?

Cheers

```
other_currencies = ['AUD','EUR','GBP','NZD']
other_currencies_plus = ['AUD','EUR','GBP','NZD','USD']
spot_spread_pivotted['Ccy'] = pd.np.where(spot_spread_pivotted[(spot_spread_pivotted['BaseCCY'].isin(other_currencies)) & (spot_spread_pivotted['PriceCCY'] == 'USD') ],
                               spot_spread_pivotted['BaseCCY'] + ('_' + spot_spread_pivotted['PriceCCY']),
                   pd.np.where(spot_spread_pivotted[(spot_spread_pivotted['PriceCCY'].isin(other_currencies)) & (spot_spread_pivotted['BaseCCY'] == 'USD') ], 
                               spot_spread_pivotted['PriceCCY'] + ('_' + spot_spread_pivotted['BaseCCY']),
                   pd.np.where(spot_spread_pivotted[(spot_spread_pivotted['BaseCCY'].isin(other_currencies)) & (spot_spread_pivotted['PriceCCY'].isin(other_currencies)) ],
                              ( spot_spread_pivotted['BaseCCY'] + '_' + 'USD') + ('/' + spot_spread_pivotted['PriceCCY'] + '_' + 'USD'),
                   pd.np.where(spot_spread_pivotted[(spot_spread_pivotted['BaseCCY'].isin(other_currencies)) & (~spot_spread_pivotted['PriceCCY'].isin(other_currencies_plus)) ],
                               (spot_spread_pivotted['BaseCCY'] + '_' + 'USD') + ('/' + 'USD' + '_' + spot_spread_pivotted['PriceCCY']),
                   pd.np.where(spot_spread_pivotted[(spot_spread_pivotted['PriceCCY'].isin(other_currencies)) & (~spot_spread_pivotted['BaseCCY'].isin(other_currencies_plus)) ],
                              ('USD' + '_' + spot_spread_pivotted['BaseCCY']) + ('/' +  spot_spread_pivotted['PriceCCY'] + '_' + 'USD')  ,
                   (('USD' + '_' + spot_spread_pivotted['BaseCCY']) + ('/' + 'USD' + '_' + spot_spread_pivotted['PriceCCY'])) )))))

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that for critical conditions using np.where is not quite right as you will miss bracket in syntax and using if is not quite right as it makes the code very slow. 
the best solution would be to have your condition and result separately as the below:

```
m = [(spot_table['Buy_Currency'].isin(other_currencies)) & (spot_table['Sell_Currency'] == 'USD'), 
     (spot_table['Sell_Currency'].isin(other_currencies)) & (spot_table['Buy_Currency'] == 'USD'), 
     (spot_table['Buy_Currency'].isin(other_currencies)) & (spot_table['Sell_Currency'].isin(other_currencies)),
     (spot_table['Buy_Currency'].isin(other_currencies)) & (~spot_table['Sell_Currency'].isin(other_currencies_plus)),
     (spot_table['Sell_Currency'].isin(other_currencies)) & (~spot_table['Buy_Currency'].isin (other_currencies_plus))]
```

and then solution as below:

```
spot_table['Ccy'] = np.select(m, [spot_table['Buy_Currency'] + ('_' + spot_table['Sell_Currency']),
                                  spot_table['Sell_Currency'] + ('_' + spot_table['Buy_Currency']),
                                  ( spot_table['Buy_Currency'] + '_' + 'USD') + ('/' + spot_table['Sell_Currency'] + '_' + 'USD'), 
                                  (spot_table['Buy_Currency'] + '_' + 'USD') + ('/' + 'USD' + '_' + spot_table['Sell_Currency']),
                                  ('USD' + '_' + spot_table['Buy_Currency']) + ('/' +  spot_table['Sell_Currency'] + '_' + 'USD')],
          ('USD' + '_' + spot_table['Buy_Currency']) + ('/' + 'USD' + '_' + spot_table['Sell_Currency']))
```